# Azure Application 502 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I just started introduction in azure, I have next code:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                browser.AllowNavigation = true;
                browser.Width = 1024;
                browser.Height = 768;
                browser.Navigate(TextBox1.Text);

               while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }

                html = browser.DocumentText;
                TextArea1.InnerText = html;
                Regex n1 = new Regex(@"Join Facebook to connect with (.+?) and others");
                MatchCollection mc4 = n1.Matches(html);
                foreach (Match m in mc4)
                {

                    ime = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    TextArea1.InnerText = "Ime: " + ime;
                }
                TextArea1.InnerText = "Ime: " + ime;

            }

        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
```

Via this code I get user Name from Facebook, everything works fine on my local machine, but on azure I always get:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

Comment: Explain about which service you are using ? webrole, webapp, vm ?